# Error al llamar una funcion T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, funciones

He creado una función con Transact-SQL que pasado el ISBN de un libro me devuelve 1 (si existe) o 0 (si no existe), pero al llamar a la función me da un error.
El código:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_llibre_ok (@isbn varchar(13)) returns bit AS
begin

    declare @existeix bit

    if exists (select lib_isbn from llibre where lib_isbn = @isbn)
    begin       
        set @existeix = 1
    end
    else
    begin
        set @existeix = 0
    end

    return @existeix

end
```

Llamo a la función con un ISBN que existe en la base de datos:

```
select fn_llibre_ok('978-84-938011')
```

Y me sale este error

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'fn_llibre_ok' no es un nombre de función reconocido.
```

No sé si es que la función está mal creada o que no la llamo bien. Si alguien puede echarme una mano se lo agradecería

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que te falta el dbo delante de la función.

prueba select dbo.fn_llibre_ok('iban')

Espero que sea esto, un saludo

Comment: Gracias @Perku era eso. Pero qué significa exactamente `dbo` y porqué se tiene que llamar así a la función?

Comment: Genial!! Me alegro, lo que te digo es más por experiencia que por conocimiento teórico. Todas las funciones se llaman con el dbo, que es el usuario propietario de la base de datos, algo así como el sysadmin. Seguro que por google hay info de esto. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Para invocar a la función hay que poner delante de la misma el esquema al que pertenece. El esquema por defecto es

```
dbo
```

Por lo tanto invocarla como

```
dbo.fn_llibre_ok('iban')
```

Sería lo correcto en la mayoría de casos.